# Free image viewer on windows with zero data collecting policy

Tags: windows, image-viewer

The old *Windows photo viewer* (which I'm fan of it) doesn't always work on my computer (windows 10). It opens some files, but for some others it shows the following error.

> Windows Photo Viewer can't display this picture because there might not be enough memory available on your computer. Close some programs that you aren't using or free some hard disk (if it's almost full), and then try again.

I open the same file with other programs and they do show them. And I don't have any memory issue. So there must be something else causing windows photo viewer not oppening them.

Therefore I'm looking for a replacement. Is there any **free** software on windows for viewing image files like jpg, png etc. and **doesn't collect** any data from you? I found a Korean good free image viewer software, reading its manual, it seems it collects some data from your usage.

Comment: Have you looked into this http://www.xnview.com or  http://www.xnview.org ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For three years I am not Windows user anymore so what I am going to suggest is just based on my search and little checking reviews. Please check these projects. All are Free (as in freedom) Software:

- [photoqt.org](https://photoqt.org)
- [interversehq.com/qview/](https://interversehq.com/qview/)
- [sourceforge.net/projects/jpegv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegv)

Comment: OP, which of these 3 did you chose? Please tell us, to help others in future. Thanks

Comment: I don't use windows. I am a serious Free Software user.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica I chose qView. My reasons; It is free. It is open, so one can really check if anything can happen against my will. I didn't notice any data collection. It's super simple and easy to use. Possible to see only the photo without extra things. And of course it fits my personal taste :)

Comment: Then feel free to post your own answer, and to accept it, in order to help others who read this question in future